# Hardcode value to end of twitter bootstrap typeahead search dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-typeahead

Im working on a search bar using twitter typeahead. Ive got it working to specifications except for one feature. I need to add a field at the bottom of every search that links to an advanced search page. Im using knockout.js to populate the data array.

```
 $('.search').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                map = {};
                $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                    map[data.text] = {
                        address: data.text2
                        , name: data.text
                    };
                    shops.push(data.text);
                });
                process(shops);
                shops = [];
            },
            minLength: 3,
            updater: function (item) {
                submit_search(item)
            },
            highlighter: function (item) {
                var p = map[item];
                var itm = ''
                         + "<div class='typeahead_wrapper'>"
                         + "<img class='typeahead_photo' src='content/images/pp-icon.png' />"
                         + "<div class='typeahead_labels'>"
                         + "<div class='typeahead_primary'>" + p.name + "</div>"
                         + "<div class='typeahead_secondary'>" + p.address + "</div>"
                         + "</div>"
                         + "</div>";
                return itm;
            },


        });
```

I was unsuccessfully trying the matcher function to return the extra item at the end of every search.. any ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

jquery append did the trick. Good ould jquery